# Terminal has disappeared as an application after software update

Tags: 14.04, gnome-terminal

Since running software update on Ubuntu Desktop 14.0.4 LTS today, there is no longer an application called 'Terminal', only XTerm and UXTerm. Is there a way to get it back?

Comment: If launching from xterm `gnome-terminal` works , it's still installed.  If you don't find it through the dash, then it might mean `/usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop` has some problem. Let us know if you can launch it through terminal and find `gnome-terminal.desktop` file and what are its contents.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
```

But this should not happen. You proably use non-standard repositories and some dependecies are broken.